# Deploy on Azure Function using GitHub Actions on push only if Function App is not executing

Tags: github, azure-functions, github-actions

I have a function app, which basically scrapes data from the web. It is a long-running one, which generally takes 9 hrs a day.
I have configured on push event for build & deploy through GitHub Actions.

Problem: When we push any change to GitHub and the function app is running it will create a mess as the running function will be stopped and triggered after deployment.

I want a solution to deploy on every push but only when the function app is not running.

Content of yml file:

```
name: dev-workflow

on:
  push:
     branches:
         - main

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: test-github-actions
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.7'

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@main

    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Pip'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"
        popd
    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://github.community/t/prevent-parallel-workflows/16370/2) response from [chrispat](https://github.community/u/chrispat/summary) (6 months ago) **there isn't
any native feature** to prevent duplicate workflows currently on Github Actions.

However, there is [this action](https://github.com/fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions) that might help to **prevent duplicated actions to start**.

Another option could be to **limit concurrent workflows runs**, you can find more about it in [this post](https://github.community/t/how-to-limit-concurrent-workflow-runs/16844).